# 'kubectl get namespace' command "namespaces is forbidden" error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I am using `kubectl get namespace` command in my Kubernetes master node, I am getting proper output. And also I configured kubectl in my local machine. When I am running the same command from local machine configured with kubectl, I am getting error like the following,

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:node:mildevkub020" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

I copied the configuration file kubelet.conf from cluster and copied into .kube/config. And also installed the kubectl. This is the process what did till now.

Result of kubectl config view is like the following,

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try `kubectl config view` and show your cluster list

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn -Check the updated question please.

Comment: Your ``serviceaccount`` doesn't have permissions to list namespaces. You can either edit existing ServiceAccount to give that permission or create new one and then use that.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. How I can edit my serviceaccount to give permission ?

Comment: Your client-certificate-data is `REDACTED`. Can you please try to use file path: like this `    client-certificate: /Users/whyn4/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /Users/whyn4/.minikube/client.key`

Comment: You are using node kubelet's kubeconfig which is not what you want. You need cluster admin kubeconfig. How did you install the cluster?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - I installed ansible in one base machine . And I cloned the kubespray from github. And I deployed using ansible playbook by defininf the list of IP address in hosts.ini file. And deployed by using the deploy plyabook.

Comment: With kubespray you should generally be able to authenticate from master node without any kubeconfig. Can you try that?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn - I did not used minikube. I used kubespray y cloning github. How I will get this .minikube client file ? Is there any configuration file for kubespray instead of this minikube?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - Ya That I already getting. This forbidden error getting only when I am accessing from outside of cluster. From cluster I copied kubelet.conf and paste into .kube/config in base machine where I installed kubectl. Do i need to copy admin.conf instead of kubelet.conf?

Comment: Yes, you need admin.conf. Read more here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#accessing-kubernetes-api

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - Can you update this  as answer. Its perfect. Kubectl is working and Tiller also successfully installed in my kubernetes cluster. Thank you for your response. Please update as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubespray by default saves cluster admin kubeconfig file as inventory/mycluster/artifacts/admin.conf. Read more here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#accessing-kubernetes-api